# Move files from CineXPlayer to OPlayer on iPad?

Tags: ipad, wifi, file-transfer

I have found myself in quite a difficult position; before travelling I transfered some movies in the .MKV-format to my iPad-app CineXPlayer, unknowing that that app could not play that file.

Now I have no computer that I can use to transfer to another app, OPlayer for iPad, but fortunately, CineXPlayer offers an easy way to transfer files from device to device - unfortunately for me, I don't have two devices. It works by letting you access your files through your iPad's local IP-address via port 8080, and accessing it from an iPhone works fine, but not from the same iPad. Any ideas how I can do this?

Any other ideas as to how I can transfer the files from app to app? Both feature a download-function with a browser, so if I could access the local 8080-port, I should be able to transfer the files internally.

Thanks for any and all help/ideas/thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is jailbroken, nothing could be simpler. Use iFile (downloadable from Cydia store). If it is not, tough luck, I have no idea. You might make it with [FileBrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8) from the AppStore, but no promises here. Good luck!

Comment: I know, but it was unfortunately _not_ jailbroken at the time. I figured it out though, OPlayer for iPhone had a "media server" as well, and so I transfered the files to my iPhone and back to the iPad. Not the fastest solution, but it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

If jailbroken use iFile, just cut and paste from/to

Files on CineXplayer are on:

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/18BA69CC-B03C-416F-A85E-84B0CD75E020/Documents
```

Files on OPlayerHD are on:

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/14BEB5AF-1363-4BB7-861A-5AE0FAD08017/Documents
```

Good luck with this starting point to mapping apps to storage on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

iFile is the way to go. However, the folder names above with all the number are out of date. You don't need new numbers. Just go to settings in iFile and choose "Show app name". Then you can easily find the apps you want to move files between using copy and paste.